# Performance measurement: How to avoid timing the assignment of toc to a variable

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:1
    tic; M=R*R; toc;
    elapsed_time = toc;
    fprintf('Function took %8f seconds\n', elapsed_time)
    x = sprintf('%0.8f',t);
    tsum = t+tsum;
end
```

This is my code and output is;

```
Elapsed time is 0.000355 seconds.

Function took 0.000483 seconds
```

The first time (elapsed time) is the time that only calculate `M=R*R`
time but when I print out my calculated time (the function took), the time value is increasing because it also calculates assigning operation (`elapsed_time = toc;`). How can I calculate  the time in the variable ignoring assigning operation?

Comment: Some general comments about your code and benchmarking in Matlab: 1) there is also a "t" unassigned that you use, that should throw an error 2) This is a very small benchmark. Even the official matlab guidelines urge you to time functions that take longer than 1/10 second. What you see is indicative (in respect with another function that you would time) but not very accurate to the actual time it takes. 3) A better benchmark can be done with the `timeit` function.

Comment: What takes time in between the two calls to `toc` is the console output. The first call to `toc` determines the time of the operation, then prints "Elapsed time is...". Next you call `toc` again, which counts the time of the operation + the printing. It's not the assignment that takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `toc` twice without a second `tic`.  You simply need to assign a variable to the `toc` output the first time.  Trust me, this variable assignment takes no time at all:

```
for i=1:1

tic; M=R*R; 
elapsed_time = toc;

fprintf('Function took %8f seconds\n', elapsed_time)
x = sprintf('%0.8f',t);


tsum = t+tsum;

end
```